# MySQL: how to overrride a row with same Primary key

Tags: mysql

Let's say I created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  num1 INT PRIMARY KEY,
  num2 INT,
  num3 INT
) NGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Let's also say that I want to insert a new row to table, and if the new row has the same primary key as one of the existing rows in the table, I want the new row to override the correspondent row.

Currently, the following SQL query will do the job:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (num1, num2, num3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num1 = num1, num2 = num2, num3 = num3;
```

The problem with this query is that it's cumbersome. Imagine a table with 20 columns. I'll have to write again all column names.

Do you know any elegant way to make this happen?

Comment: have you tried `REPLACE` ?

Comment: *"The problem with this query is that it's cumbersome. Imagine a table with 20 columns. I'll have to write again all column names."* Indeed that's why you should normalize as incrementing column names like you have are great candidates for normalisation... If this is "pseudo" code you should give a better user case which matches your question better and or user case better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say hi to MySQL's `REPLACE`.

Per mySQL documentation:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted

Thus, you could simply

```
REPLACE INTO my_table (num1, num2, num3) VALUES (1,2,3);
```

if the row does not exist, it'll work as a regular `INSERT`. If it does exist, it'll be deleted+inserted (in your eyes, it'll look like an `UPDATE`)

Be advised. You could feel tempted to always use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT` regardless of what you're doing. That would inconvenient (I learned the hard way) as the Replace has a lot more overhead

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can skip the primary key, because that has the same value as the existing row by definition, or else it wouldn't be a duplicate row.

Note that you use `VALUES(columname)` or else you won't be overriding the values with the ones from your VALUES list.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (num1, num2, num3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num2 = VALUES(num2), num3 = VALUES(num3);
```

Or as the comment above mentioned, use REPLACE:

```
REPLACE INTO my_table (num1, num2, num3) VALUES (1, 2, 3);
```

(Note that these do two different things. You might like to read my answer to ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update/548570#548570).)

> *The problem with this query is that it's cumbersome. Imagine a table with 20 columns. I'll have to write again all column names.*

Hmm. Are the Copy & Paste buttons on your computer broken?

Perhaps you would like us to trim the crust off your bread for you? (joking)

Honestly, sometimes software development involves a bit of work. Typing 20 column names is not the most boring thing you're going to do this week.

Comment: *"Typing 20 column names is not the most boring thing you're going to do this week. "*  About time they implement a IDE with voice to text so you can talk nerd (programming) language.. I wonder how this would work on a busy office...

Comment: @RaymondNijland that would be fun for speech-to-code-bombing pranks... imaging walking around devops guys reciting "sudo ar em space hyphen ar ef space slash" and then run away like crazy before they butcher you :)